# Why doesn't my setup of using a screen with an apple monitor work, and how do I debug it?

Tags: display, hdmi, kvm

I have a screen that is set to use HDMI1. The screen works fine with my mac when HDMI <-> HDMI is used with OSx. However, when I connect the HDMI through a switch (to be able to use multiple macs/computers), it no longer works. The display IS recognized by the mac, but the screen remains blank with "check signal".

I am sure all cables are connected properly.

Is there a reason for this not to work?

This is the KVM switch I use:

https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B08C7FF3RB/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o08_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: What is the display? Note that your hub only supplies 4k @ 30Hz, which may or may not be suitable for your display. Also: are there different cables involved?

Comment: the display is a Samsung, it shows S27B550 in the Colour profile. I didn't realise there are such limitations by the hub (4k @ 30Hz), but I don't know how to set it up to match these limitations. Where do I do that? The drop down for the refresh rate just gives me 50hz or 60hz.

Comment: Hmm. Your display is only 1920 x 1080, and those HDMI ports can maintain a higher refresh rate for smaller sizes. So I don't know what's going on. Have you tried both cables either side of the KVM directly?  (To make sure it's not the cables.)
Have you tried both HDMI ports on the display? Ultimately, if it doesn't work when the KVM is involved, then it's the KVM.