# What are the options to stream my laptop screen to HDMI?

Tags: keyboard, hdmi, streaming, kvm

This is a follow up question to this:

[Why doesn't my setup of using a screen with an apple monitor work, and how do I debug it?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/446771/why-doesnt-my-setup-of-using-a-screen-with-an-apple-monitor-work-and-how-do-i?noredirect=1#comment647266_446771)

I gave up on the idea of using this KVM for now, but I am starting to wonder if I am in the wrong direction for this day and age.

I did a search about HDMI streaming through Wifi, and found this:

https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k=Wireless+Display+Adapter+osx+windows+keyboard&crid=2I1RG78I3VB6Z&sprefix=wireless+display+adapter+osx+windows+keyboard%2Caps%2C79&ref=nb_sb_noss

I am lost.

I want to be able to use one external keyboard and mouse and one screen with three computers: a PC laptop, and two Macbooks with latest macOS. The PC laptop has regular USB connection, one Macbook has HDMI and USB-C, and the other only USB-C. I have many adaptors of many kinds, but some might be incompatiable, as I read online.

The keyboard/mouse I have are wireless and have a USB dongle through which they communicate with the device (one device).

In this zoo of devices, adapters and cables, what am I looking for? I just want to connect several devices to one keyboard/mouse/screen and am lost...

Comment: From the other suggestions and tests you were given, like the cables etc?

Comment: I just want to know what to look for in a Wifi adapter instead of KVM switch for handling the keyboard, mouse and screen.

Comment: I do not have WiFi enabled keyboard/mouse, just Bluetooth type. Do yours show up on BT menu

Comment: Yes, it is BT, sorry. So maybe BT for keyboard/mouse and Wifi for streaming into the HDMI? I am open to suggestions.